# Can Ansys import parameters

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, ansys, ansys-workbench

In Ansys workbench is it possible to import parameters with part geometry? Eg. if I create part or assembly in Creo or SolidWorks and define parameters for this geometry, can I export parameters with geometry and import and use those parameters in Ansys workbench (structural analysis)? Can you describe process? 
If you answer question please also write which version of ansys and what program can be used in such way.

Comment: Can you include whether you have already checked importing geometry and cad files from other applications ? Data exchange is one of the trivial subjects in all engineering software, and for that reason I guess the documentation should cover this topic thoroughly.

Comment: @GürkanÇetin static geometry is trivial indeed. But a parametric model is not, if it were then there would be no reason to use any of the other software around. However, it is indeed possible to use the original application to regenerate the model form ansys its just that this is work so i dont actually go further into this.

Comment: Alright, from the wording it was not clear to me whether the parameters were related to geometric or material or element type properties of the problem.